# REST calls from angular front-end unable to hit spring boot controller

Tags: angular, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have been trying to call Spring boot REST services from my angular application and few of the REST calls are not hitting the controller.

Recently, I have added proxy settings to my *proxy.config.json* similar to below.

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080/api",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": "true"   
        } 
    }
}
```

Service is running on port 8080 and UI is running on port 4200.

I'm calling the service like below :

```
public getData(param1: number, param2: number): Observable<SomeDTO> {

        return this.authHttp.get(this.basePath + param1 + '/someEndPoint/' + param2, this.options).map(response => response.json() || {});

}
```

When I'm hardcoding the the URL to the service, it's working fine. But when I'm using proxy settings with some dynamic path, I am getting 400 Bad Request straight away.

Can anyone help me what could be wrong here?

Comment: Please post `controller` code and error.

Comment: Have you checked inside the DeveloperTools how the request from FE to BE looks like?

Comment: @hrdkisback Controller code is simple POST request which takes some DTO and saves it. It works great if I hardcode the URL of the service.

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig request doesn't reach back-end at all. I get Bad request as a response with no error no warning nothing.

Comment: I know that your backend doesn't receive the request. What I meant is the outgoing request from your client. You can check that inside your browsers developer tools under the network section. Is the request correct? Because I would think that the request made is worng e.g. it's calling localhost:8080/api/api or anything similar and since you haven't defined a controller for a request like that you get a bad request. Please check inside your browsers developer tools under the network section, how the request made from your front end to the back end looks like.